# SQLite database file path in .NET MAUI app results in null string from Path.Combine()

Tags: .net, sqlite, maui

I'm trying to add a SQLite database to my .NET MAUI app, but cannot get the path of the database file.

When I add a break point at this code

```cs
string dbpath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
    "clientdb.db3");
```

the `dbpath` variable is `null` when debugging the app and the table method  does not display anything.

I've tried changing `LocalApplictionData` into `CommonApplicationData` and also `MyDocuments`, but it does not work.
the rest of the code is:

```
   public SQLiteAsyncConnection _dbConnection;

        public SqlightServiceClass()
        {
            CreatSqlightConnection();
        }
        public async void CreatSqlightConnection()
        {

            if (_dbConnection == null)
            {
                string path1 = FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory;
                string dbpath = Path.Combine(path1, "Employees.db3");

                _dbConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);

                await _dbConnection.CreateTableAsync<ClientInfoModel>();
            }

        }
```

Comment: `LocalApplicationData` is a path in the WIndows OS. It might not be available on the OS you are using.

Comment: May I ask if you still meet this issue? If so, what platform or API level you used?

Comment: There is a similar issue on Github : [sqlite path null](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6145). You could have a look

Comment: the platform is android API 33

Comment: Does ```Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)``` return null?

Comment: And you may refer to the official document [.NET MAUI local databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite) and [samples](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/Data/TodoSQLite).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Environment`, you could use the [File System Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers#app-data-directory) from MAUI Essentials:

```cs
string dbpath = Path.Combine(
    FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory,
    "clientdb.db3");
```

It will provide the private application data directory on each platform.

In order to see what the paths are, you can either put a breakpoint after the statement that combines the path or output the directory part of the path to the console:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory);
```

The `Path.Combine()` method will throw an `ArgumentNullException` if the path is actually `null`, as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine).

Comment: does not work, with no error or exception but the path is still null

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the line where you create the string and inspect the `AppDataDirectory` property? It shouldn't be `null`, because then you'd see an `ArgumentNullException` as per the [documentation of the Path.Combine() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine).

Comment: yes, it gives an exception but not every time I run the app, many times I run the app without any exception, and without data being displayed when it throws an exception it says that it's a user exception, not an error

Comment: Then please show more of the code. The problem may be occurring somewhere else.

Comment: @HossamTash: What do you mean by user exception?

Comment: ```        public async void CreatSqlightConnection()
        {

            if (_dbConnection == null)
            {
                string path1 = FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory;
                string dbpath = Path.Combine(path1, "Employees.db3");

                _dbConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);

                await _dbConnection.CreateTableAsync<ClientInfoModel>();
            }

        }
```

Comment: @HossamTash Please add the code to your question, **never** post entire code sections in comments. It belongs into the question and only there. Just update it.